# EF Core 2 GroupBy Count predicate ignored

Tags: c#, asp.net, ef-core-2.0

I currently have the following code:

```
var result = query<Items>()
            .Where(x => x.Id == someId)
            .SelectMany(x => x.SubItems)
            .GroupBy(x => x.SubItemId)
            .Select(x => new ItemModel
            {   
                SubItemId = x.Key,
                SpecialItemCount = x.Where(y => y.IsSpecial == false).Count(),
            })
            .ToList()...
```

When I call "Count()" it queries all subitem count ignoring my predicate "y.IsSpecial". I tried that on EF Core 2.0.X and EF Core 2.1 preview 2, is that possibly a bug?

Comment: I believe that `GroupBy` isn't yet implemented in EF Core so this will drag all the table into memory and group locally.

Comment: it's supported in 2.1, no warnings in console

Comment: Yes, not sure how well it works though. Note you can also write the count as `x.Count(y => !y.IsSpecial)`

Comment: Will take a look when have some time. For clarity, it doesn't happen on 2.0.2, right? Only on 2.1 preview 2?

Comment: It's 2.1, preview-2 final. Unfortunately I don't remember which exact version it was (2.0.x)

Comment: Reproduced. Apparently is a bug, I don't knw if they are aware of it or not (consider posting it to their issue tracker). Trying the usual EF6 workaround tricks like conditional `Sum`, either do client evaluation or get invalid SQL exceptions. Unfortunately looks like that even 2.1 won't be ready for good stable server side querying.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here with EF Core 3.0. Seems to be bug in EF - you can workaround by using

```
SpecialItemCount = x.Sum(y => y.IsSpecial ? 0 : 1)
```

instead of

```
SpecialItemCount = x.Count(y => y.IsSpecial == false)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade to EF Core 2.1 where GroupBy is supported : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-2.1