# EF Core Group By translation support on conditional sum

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-core-2.1

I was really excited to hear that EF Core 2.1 will be supporting group by translations. I downloaded the preview and started testing it out but found that I am still not getting group by translations in a number of places.

In the code snippet below, the query for TotalFlagCases will prevent the group by translation from working. Is there anyway that I can rewrite this so that I can have group by support? Or perhaps another approach that I can take?

There are a lot of rows in this table and I don't want .NET to have to load all of these rows. I use row level data as well, but only about 15 records at a time.

```
var headerTask = (from c in cases
    group c by 1
    into g
    select new CaseHeader
    {
        TotalCases = g.Count(),
        // ... A number of other aggregates
        TotalFlagCases = g.Where(a => a.Flag).Sum(b => 1),
    })
.DefaultIfEmpty(new CaseHeader()).FirstAsync();
```

Comment: *"but found that I am still not getting group by translations in a number of places"* Unfortunately that's the reality. Tried using intermediate projection, got invalid SQL exception. All you can do is to post it/ask in their issue tracker. But the conclusion so far is that even 2.1 is not ready for such type of queries. See [another weird behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50160399/ef-core-2-groupby-count-predicate-ignored).

Comment: I'm disappointed to say the least. I use Linqkit and Expressions because I have dynamic filtering and group by logic. The code looks elegant in C# but it is ugly when I have to do it in a stored procedure and difficult to optimize because there are parameters all over the place, each of which I have to check for NULLs because I may not actually be using is it in a particular query.

I feel so close! If I could just get conditional Sum or Count to be translated, then I could avoid these ugly stored procs.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is a way to do a conditional sum in this version of EF Core. Provided code is not going to be translated into desired SQL with `GROUP BY` but maybe some future version will support it this way. For now you can try something like this:

```
var headerTask = cases
    .Select(c => new
    {
        c.Flag,
        c.YourKey,
        //other properties
    })
    .GroupBy(c => c.YourKey, (k, g) => new CaseHeader
    {
        TotalCases = g.Count(),
        // ... A number of other aggregates
        TotalFlagCases = g.Sum(b => a.Flag ? 1 : 0)
    });
```

When you project your entity into an anonymous type and then group it and use conditional operator in an aggregate function it will be translated into SQL with `GROUP BY` and aggregates like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS [TotalCases], SUM(CASE
    WHEN [c].[Flag] = 1
    THEN 1 ELSE 0
END) AS [TotalFlagCases]
FROM [Cases] AS [c]
GROUP BY [c].[YourKey]
```

When you do not project it to an anonymous type so when there is the above `Select` function missing it will not be translated into SQL with `GROUP BY`. It looks like the query translator for this prerelease does not support it or it's a bug.

Comment: I almost couldn't believe it but that works! A bit verbose though. Could you address one other issue for my particular case? I am not grouping over a field but rather the whole dataset, e.g., "SELECT count(*) FROM cases" as opposed to "SELECT count(*) FROM cases GROUP BY SomeField". I can't seem to get it to work for that scenario. I get an error saying that my fields could not be bound.

Comment: @jaromey Use key in GroupBy like `b => new { Key = b.Id - b.Id }` or `b.Id * 0` etc. You cannot use `new { Key = 1 }` because SQL Server requires at least one column in GROUP BY. It's a bit hacky but it works. Maybe I can find a better solution.

Comment: Or add Key into anonymous type like `Key = c.Id * 0` and reference it in group by `b => new { b.Key }`. You can also use conditional operator for key like `Key = c.Flag ? 1 : 1` etc

Comment: Unfortunately, it evaluates the linq expression locally when I do that. However, I'll mark your answer as the accepted one since it does work except for my edge case.

Comment: @jaromey I tested it and it does translate it to SQL with GROUP BY. Do you have sth like`.GroupBy(c => new { Key = c.Id * 0 }, (k, g) => new CaseHeader (...)`? Note: key is anonymous type

Comment: I'm sorry, it does work. I just didn't follow instructions correctly :)

Comment: Lifesaver, after seeing it it makes total sense that it has to be done this way (condition with fallback to zero) if you think about the SQL that needs to be generated as filtering in groups is not supported. That said it is not super intuitive coming from Linq.

Comment: this is brilliant @arekzyla. Thank you.