# EF Core 2.1 RC 1 GroupBy still evaluates locally

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I upgraded an ASP.NET Core project from version **2.0.x** to **2.1.0-rc1** by following the [official guide](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2018/05/07/asp-net-core-2-1-0-rc1-now-available/) from ASP.NET Blog. The **EF Core** packages were updated to the same version as well. The database provider that i am using is [Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer). I was waiting for this upgrade with anticipation since i needed a lot the [LINQ GroupBy translation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-2.1) feature. One of my queries is the following:

```
await _db.Documents
         .ApplyFilter(options)
         .Where(x => x.SubscriptionId == subscriptionId && x.Status != DocumentStatus.Deleted)
         .GroupBy(document => new { document.SubscriptionId })
         .Select(group => new {
            Total = group.Sum(x => x.Total),
            TotalDiscount = group.Sum(x => x.TotalDiscount),
            TotalNet = group.Sum(x => x.TotalNet != null ? x.TotalNet.Value * (decimal)x.CurrencyRate : 0),
            SubTotal = group.Sum(x => x.SubTotal != null ? x.SubTotal.Value * (decimal)x.CurrencyRate : 0),
            TotalSalesTax = group.Sum(x => x.TotalSalesTax != null ? x.TotalSalesTax.Value * (decimal)x.CurrencyRate : 0),
            TotalTax = group.Sum(x => x.TotalTax != null ? x.TotalTax.Value * (decimal)x.CurrencyRate : 0),
            TotalPayable = group.Sum(x => x.TotalPayable != null ? x.TotalPayable.Value * (decimal)x.CurrencyRate : 0)
        })
        .ToListAsync();
```

When this query runs i still receive a warning that states:

> EFCore Linq Query Could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.

So i would like to ask if am i doing something (terribly) wrong or this feature is not yet available as it is advertised? Has any of you tried something similar? Thank you in advance for your help.

---

### Edit

For the shake of testing the problem is tried the following query (removed the conditional checks from `Sum` method) as **Ivan Stoev** suggested in the comments, but the result is the same.

```
await _db.Documents
         .ApplyFilter(options)
         .Where(x => x.SubscriptionId == subscriptionId && x.Status != DocumentStatus.Deleted)
         .GroupBy(document => new { document.SubscriptionId })
         .Select(group => new {
            Total = group.Sum(x => x.Total),
            TotalDiscount = group.Sum(x => x.TotalDiscount),
            TotalNet = group.Sum(x => x.TotalNet),
            SubTotal = group.Sum(x => x.SubTotal),
            TotalSalesTax = group.Sum(x => x.TotalSalesTax),
            TotalTax = group.Sum(x => x.TotalTax),
            TotalPayable = group.Sum(x => x.TotalPayable)
          })
          .ToListAsync();
```

---

### Solution

After experimenting i figured out the following. I post it in case someone has the same problem. The following query in perfectly translated into a T-SQL statement and thus not evaluating on the client.

```
await (from d in _db.Documents.ApplyFilter(options)
       where d.SubscriptionId == subscriptionId && d.Status != DocumentStatus.Deleted
       group d by d.SubscriptionId into g
       select new {
          Total = g.Sum(x => x.Total/* * Convert.ToDecimal(x.CurrencyRate)*/),
          TotalDiscount = g.Sum(x => x.TotalDiscount/* * Convert.ToDecimal(x.CurrencyRate)*/),
          TotalNet = g.Sum(x => x.TotalNet/* * Convert.ToDecimal(x.CurrencyRate)*/),
          SubTotal = g.Sum(x => x.SubTotal/* * Convert.ToDecimal(x.CurrencyRate)*/),
          TotalSalesTax = g.Sum(x => x.TotalSalesTax/* * Convert.ToDecimal(x.CurrencyRate)*/),
          TotalTax = g.Sum(x => x.TotalTax/* * Convert.ToDecimal(x.CurrencyRate)*/),
          TotalPayable = g.Sum(x => x.TotalPayable/* * Convert.ToDecimal(x.CurrencyRate)*/)
       }).ToListAsync();
```

The obvious difference is that i use the **LINQ query syntax** instead of the **extension methods**. Also i commented out the multiplication with the `CurrencyRate` property as **it also results in evaluating the query locally**. This seems quite strange as the query syntax also translates in extension methods under the hood.

I also opened an issue in the Github repository of Entity Framework Core
 which you can find [here](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/12023)

Comment: You didn't even told which provider you are using

Comment: Can you show us a similar query (without the `GroupBy`) that doesn't generate that warning so we can compare the two?

Comment: @Tseng i edited the post. I am using [Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer) (so i am using Sql Server).

Comment: Offtopic, `x.TotalNet != null ? x.TotalNet.Value * (decimal)x.CurrencyRate : 0` can be shortened to `(x.TotalNet ?? 0) * (decimal)x.CurrencyRate`. I'm also not sure if `(decimal)` serves  a purpose here. This may also touch on the reason why EF Core can't translate your linq query but I haven't confirmed that yet.

Comment: @mjwills There are queries that are evaluated on the server and others that are evaluated on the client as explained [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/client-eval). GroupBy was one of the extension methods that could not be translated into a T-SQL statement and thus it run on the server. This was supposed to be fixed in EF Core 2.1 as [announced](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-2.1) but i really struggle to see it in action. So, my other queries work as expected. I just try to find out if this specific case in my error or not implemented yet.

Comment: The problem seems to be the conditional `Sum` - for some reason (bug in the translation logic) it's not translated. The ugly workaround seem to be using intermediate anonymous type projection with all needed fields before `GroupBy`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50162978/ef-core-group-by-translation-support-on-conditional-sum

Comment: @Flater indeed using the null-coalescing operator offers a more compact and readable syntax. `CurrencyRate` property is of type `double` so casting to `decimal` is required in order to multiply the 2 values.

Comment: @IvanStoev i edited my post and tried your suggestion but the result is exactly the same.

Comment: Try opening an issue on GitHub if you think its a bug. https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues There it will get a closer attention to the developers and will be tracked in case it's really a bug or oversight

Comment: @Tseng that seems like a good suggestion. I opened this as an issue which you can find [here](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/12023)

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer and mark it as solved once the grace time is over

Answer (score 1):

In my case the grouping was evaluated client-side for this query:

```
await context.MyCollection
.GroupBy(x => x.Tag.Id)
.ToDictionaryAsync(x => x.Key, x => x.Count());
```

Changing it to the below one made it evaluated server-side:

```
await context.MyCollection
.GroupBy(x => x.Tag.Id)
.Select(g => new {g.Key, Count = g.Count()})
.ToDictionaryAsync(arg => arg.Key, arg => arg.Count);
```

Answer (score 0):

GroupBy is a red herring.

Using the query syntax compiles down to using the extension methods, so that's not the issue.

The only difference that I can see between the version in your edit and the version in query syntax is that you do `_db.Documents.ApplyFilter(...)` in the cases where group by is still evaluated locally. I'm guessing that this causes the return type to shift to something else, and the wrong overloads to be picked, or some similar detail that confuses the query translator - this would cause *all* of the LINQ operators (Where, Select, GroupBy, etc) to be evaluated locally.

Comment: I am sorry for omitting this. The `ApplyFilter` method contains some more `Where` methods and returns an `IQueryable`. I have checked that it does not make any difference if i add it or not.